# Reversing string from user input, repeating until certain string is entered

Tags: python

I'm attempting to write a program that prints a reverse string taken from user input, and repeats until "Quit", "quit", or "q" is entered.

Ex: If the input is:

```
Line One
Line Two
quit
```

then the output is:

```
enO eniL 
owT eniL
```

Currently, the loop does not terminate, nor does it move to the second line of input. It continues to print the reverse of Line One.

```
s = input()
while s != "quit":
    print (s[::-1])
```

Comment: So only every second word should be reversed?

Comment: Every word should be reversed, until the string "Quit" is entered, then the program should stop looping.

Comment: Then your output doesnt make any sense at all

Comment: You can reverse with: `''.join(reversed(s))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to input a new string each time through the loop.  The code you have only inputs a single string, then either quits or prints its reverse forever:

```
s = input()
while s not in {"quit", "Quit", "q"}:
    print (s[::-1])
```

You can change it to:

```
s = input()
while s != "quit":
    print (s[::-1])
    s = input()
```

This will obtain a new string each time through.

Comment: Doesn't fit the expected output, which is totally weird

Comment: Expected output changes every second word's order, how does your answer reflect that?

Comment: This seems to work, however, how would I make it terminate if s != "quit", "Quit", or "q" ? I tried it with commas, but that syntax doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to quit when a line containing "quit", "Quit", or "q" is entered.

Comment: @chrispbacon Look at it now.  OP had three lines in the example, but had not placed it in a code block so they came out as one.  I indented it as a code block (without adding any newlines), and the result matches perfectly now.  It was nothing more than a simple formatting problem, and the question makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Doesn't `input()` include the trailing newline? If so, you need to remove it with e.g. `input = input.rstrip()`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart No, it doesn't.  Try it ;)  It's different from reading a line from a file.

Comment: @strawhatsoju By the way, `s not in {"quit", "Quit", "q"}` is equivalent to `s != "quit" and s != "Quit" and s != "q"`, but a more compact way to express it.  `{"quit", "Quit", "q"}` is a Python `set`, and `s not in x` simply tests if `s` is not contained in `x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input()

quit_txt = ['Quit', 'quit', 'QUIT', 'q']

while s not in quit_txt:
    print(s[::-1])
    s = input()
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer